# Pinging in an embed doesn't work correctly with discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(ctx):
user1 = discord.Member
channel = bot.get_channel(654805249311375400)
embed= discord.Embed(title='Welcome to Kitty\'s Play Place <3', description='Welcome! We hope you enjoy your time at Kitty\'s play place {} \n ----------------------------------------------------------------------- \n Please check <#654820877304856606> to avoid any problems \n after please go to <#654806729162227743> and <#654806701123567616> \n To gain access to our chats, click the reaction in the channels mentioned above \n ----------------------------------------------------------------------- \n'. format(user1), colour=discord.Color.red())
embed.set_image(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/654804320222707723/665897722213171205/ezgif-7-ec547b785e7d.gif')
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

So I have this code, and what's weird is that it works, except that the user ping shows up as:

`<class 'discord.member.Member'>`

instead of the `username`.

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: have you tried user.mention? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.User.mention

Comment: Where would i put that?

Comment: It gives me this now <property object at 0x03BA1D20>

Comment: *Exactly* what do you expect  `<class 'discord.member.Member'>` to be, instead of what it currently is?

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding the improper indentation, you're assigning the [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) class itself to `user`.
You need to use an instance of that class.

See the [How do I get a specific model? section of the FAQ in discord.py's documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-a-specific-model).

If you're intending to use the member that just joined, [`on_member_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join) gets passed that `Member` object, not a [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) object, and you can just use that.

Once you have the specific object, you can use the [`Member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mention) attribute for the corresponding string to mention them with.